# jsoup : parse data just after some tag (h2)

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Suppose this is the HTML which I am using to parse through jsoup in java

```
<div id = "report-content">
    <h2>Name <div>or a nick name</div></h2>
    Doe
    <h2>Occupation</h2>
    Singer
    <h2>Lives in</h2>
    Honkong
 </div>
```

How can I fetch data like

```
Name
Doe

Occupation
Singer

Lives in 
Honkong
```

in jsoup?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following snippet:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse("<div id = \"report-content\">\r\n" + "    <h2>Name <div>or a nick name</div></h2>\r\n"
        + "    Doe\r\n" + "    <h2>Occupation</h2>\r\n" + "    Singer\r\n" + "    <h2>Lives in</h2>\r\n" + "    Honkong\r\n"
        + " </div>");

Element rootElement = document.getElementById("report-content");
for (Node node : rootElement.childNodes()) {
    if (node instanceof TextNode) {
        // print text after h2 tag
        System.out.println(((TextNode) node).text().trim());
    } else if (node instanceof Element) {
        // print text of the h2 tag without inner elements (div)
        Element element = (Element) node;
        if ("h2".equals(element.tagName())) {
            System.out.println(element.ownText());
        }
    }
}
```